# Springboot project Openshift router giving empty response

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift, router

I have deployed the Spring boot application on Fabric and int logs there is no error and application is up and running, the router is pointing to correct service and correct port too.  Not sure why am I getting empty response for the router.

```
2018-08-01 06:52:02,502 [main] INFO  org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter [] 87 - Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-08-01 06:52:02,700 [main] INFO  org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter []  - Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-08-01 06:52:02,700 [main] INFO  org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter [] 87 - Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-08-01 06:52:02,903 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol [] 180 - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2018-08-01 06:52:02,903 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol [] 180 - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2018-08-01 06:52:03,304 [main] INFO  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool [] 180 - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2018-08-01 06:52:03,304 [main] INFO  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool []  - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2018-08-01 06:52:04,009 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer []  - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-01 06:52:04,009 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [] 87 - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-01 06:52:04,104 [main] INFO  com.xx.xx.Application []  - Started Application in 120.101 seconds (JVM running for 123.533)
```

Opening the terminal of running pod and running below command giving me expected results:

```
sh-4.2$ curl localhost:8080/rest/v1/hello
{"hello":"world"}
```

Router is also pointing to 8080 port number.

Curl Command giving below response:

```
    $ curl -kv http://xx.xx.com
    * Rebuilt URL to: http://xx.xx.com/
    * timeout on name lookup is not supported
    *   Trying (IP Address) ...
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to xx.xx.com
(IP Address) port 80 (#0)
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > Host: xx.xx.com
    > User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
    > Accept: */*
    >
    * Empty reply from server
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    * Connection #0 to host xx.xx.com left intact
    curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Please let me know in case more details are required.

Comment: how did you configure proxy for the domain xx.xx.com ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan where can I find it to provide you details, As per my knowledge I have not configured any proxy .

Comment: you should know how to translate real domain  xx.xx.com to your server which you run `curl localhost:8080/rest/v1/hello` .

Comment: Inside of pod, what happens if you run ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080/rest/v1/hello``. This will use the IP for the pod and not loopback interface. It will confirm whether is actually accepting requests from outside of the pod, such as may come through haproxy router. Also what happens for ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080/`` inside pod since from outside you don't seem to give sub path. Maybe nothing is handling requests on root of site.

Comment: I am able to hit the route but not sure how it worked. I created a new test route and everything seems to be fine now. 

Can someone please explain if have any idea.